# How to import a module from sub directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

I failed to import a module from sub directory in python. Below is my project structure.

```
./main.py
./sub
./sub/__init__.py
./sub/aname.py
```

when I run `python main.py`, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import sub.aname
  File "/Users/dev/python/demo/sub/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from aname import print_func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aname'
```

I don't know it failed to load the module `aname`. Below is the source code:

`main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sub.aname

print_func('zz')
```

`sub/__init__.py`:

```
from aname import print_func
```

`sub/aname.py`:

```
def print_func( par ):
   print ("Hello : ", par)
   return
```

I am using python 3.6.0 on MacOS

Comment: The module is either `.aname` or `sub.aname`. There's no global module `aname`.

Comment: try `import sub.aname`

Comment: I tried to `import sub.aname` on main.py but got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your Python scripts.

#### Relative import

First, to do relative import, you must use a leading dots (see [Guido's Decision](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision) about Relative Imports syntax).

In `sub/__init__.py`, replace:

```
from aname import print_func
```

with:

```
from .aname import print_func
```

#### Importing a function

To import a function from a given module you can use the `from ... import ...` statement.

In `main.py`, replace:

```
import sub.aname
```

with:

```
from sub import print_func
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sub import aname
aname.print_func('zz')
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most elegant solution is to use relative imports in your submodule `sub`:

#### `sub.__init__.py`

```
from .aname import print_func
```

---

But you also need to import the `print_func` in `main.py` otherwise you'll get a `NameError` when you try to execute `print_func`:

#### `main.py`

```
from sub import print_func   # or: from sub.aname import print_func

print_func('zz')
```