# import packages not work python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I create a packages in python 3 and went a try to import this in my main folder this is not work

My architecture like this

```
--mainFolder
  --__init__.py
  --start.py
  --packages
    --__init__.py
    --file1.py
    --file2.py
```

when i start my programme with the console like this

```
python3 start.py
```

i have this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 8, in <module>
    from packages import Class1
ImportError: cannot import name 'Class1'
```

my fist **init** file in my mainFolder is empty

in my **init** in my packages i try

1  `from .file1 import Class1`

2 `from . import Class1`

3 `from . import file1`

in my start.py i try to call my module in many ways

1  `from packages import Class1`

2`from .packages import Class1`

3`from . import Class1`

***EDIT***

in my `packages/file1` my code like this

```
import time
import sys

Class Class1(objet):

  def run(self):
      print('test')
```

in a call this file in my start.py like this

```
Class1().run()
```

i try this [How to import a module from sub directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010017/how-to-import-a-module-from-sub-directory)

this [Cannot import modules in Python3 from sub directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631143/cannot-import-modules-in-python3-from-sub-directory)

and this  [Importing module from sub-directory works in Python 2, but not Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415473/importing-module-from-sub-directory-works-in-python-2-but-not-python-3)

I think my file **init** not load because went i add this

```
sys.path.append('path/to/my/package')
```

in import my packages its work but pycharm give me and error each time and not compile the script

Comment: `Class1` isn't in `packages`; it's in `packages.file1`.

Comment: yes Class1 is it in the file1

Comment: Edit your question to include all of the code.  The problem is likely in the code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Gordon said:

If Class1 is in file1.py then you can import it with

```
from packages.file1 import Class1
```

You can also import Class1 into packages/**init**.py with

```
from file1 import Class1
```

Then import straight from packages

```
from packages import Class1
```